# Display video in view page

Tags: php, sql, laravel, video

I am working on a simple basic crud, I am storing my registered users with a video.
the file type I am using is local, the registration goes on fine. but i can't seem to display and play my videos on my view page.

this is my registration function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name'                  => 'required|string', 'max:255', 
            'email'                 => 'required|string',
            'password'              => 'required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults(),
            'phone'                 => 'required|string', 
            'insta'                 => 'required|string',
            'video'                 => 'required', 
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([ 'message' => $validator->errors() ]);
        }

        try{

            if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
                $sub = str_replace('" "', '_',$request->company);
                $path = Storage::disk('local')
                ->putFileAs("user/video-{$sub}",$request->video,$request->video->getClientOriginalName());
            } 
            
            $user = User::create([
                'name'                  => $request->name, 
                'email'                 => $request->email, 
                'password'              => Hash::make($request->password),
                'phone'                 => $request->phone, 
                'insta'                 => $request->insta,
                'video'                 => $path,
            ]);

         
             event(new Registered($user));
               
                 Auth::login($user);
                

             return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('success','Registerd succesfully!');
        }

        catch (\Exception $e){
            $payload=[
                'status'=>'fail',
                'details'=>$e->getMessage()
            ];
            return response()->json(['message' => $payload]);
        }

        
       

        

        
    }
```

this is my show function

```
 public function show($user)
    {
        $user = User::findorfail($user);
        return view('Pages.Admin.Candidate.show',['user' => $user]);
    }
```

and this is my view

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    {{-- <video controls="" src=" {{ url('storage/'.$user->video) }}" class="bs-card-video"></video> --}}

                    <video width="auto" height="auto" controls>   
                      <source src=" {{ url('storage/'.$user->video) }}" type="video/mp4">   
                      <source src=" {{ url('storage/'.$user->video) }}" type="video/ogg">   
                      Your browser does not support the video tag. 
                    </video> 
                   
                </div>
            </div>
```

But it still doesn't show the video.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->phone = $request->phone;
    $user->insta = $request->insta;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
        $file = $request->file('video');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('user/videos/', $filename);
        $user->video = $filename;
    }
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Your Route

```
Route::post('/user/store', 'UserController@store');
```

Your Create View

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
   <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
   <input type="text" name="phone" required><br>
   <input type="text" name="insta" required><br>
   <input type="password" name="password" required><br>
   <input type="file" name="video" required><br> 
   <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Your Find view

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">

                <video width="auto" height="auto" controls>   
                  <source src=" {{ asset('user/videos/' .$user->video) }}" type="video/mp4">   
                  <source src=" {{ asset('user/videos/' .$user->video) }}" type="video/ogg">   
                  Your browser does not support the video tag. 
                </video> 
               
            </div>
        </div>
```

Good luck it should work

Comment: thanks@Nathan Mwamba i have tried it, it saves but it just doesn't show in the view

Comment: but your video is stored in the public folder?

Comment: it was stored in the storage folder , i had to store it in the public folder for it to work @Nathan

Comment: run this command            php artisan storage:link, then try to store you file

Comment: yes, i ran the storage link before my question, I had to unlink it and the store in a public storage like you suggested, works now. thanks @Nathan Mwamba